# JOAuth, a java-based OAuth 1 (final) and OAuth 2 (draft 10) library. How do I use it?

Tags: java, oauth, joauth

I've seen too many questions in here (SO) asking about OAuth and how to connect to Facebook Graph API or Twitter API using OAuth protocol.

I've discovered [JOAuth](http://code.google.com/p/joauth/) (from Google Code) and I was wondering how can I use it? What other features does JOAuth provide and does it fare well with other java oauth libraries?

Comment: Please check periodically for new updates (Just updated the library) and also, please provide feedback, if possible.

Comment: hi i'm pretty new to tomcat servlets and services. i post a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297730/java-tomcat-how-to-use-joauth-properly please let me know if you can assist in any way

Comment: @ufk, thanks for using `JOAuth`. I have replied to your post accordingly. Let me know of other issues if it arises. PS, how did you hear about JOAuth?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Seeing that I've written JOAuth, I thought it would be appropriate to answer this question on SO. I didn't find the option to make this question a community wiki. :(*

*Note* I'm not here to discuss [OAuth Authorization](http://oauth.net/). There are various sites dedicated for this.

JOAuth comes with a wonderful feature. It has a controller `OAuthServlet` that manages your HTTP Redirect response from the Service provider.
The way to configure `OAuthServlet` to your web application, simply declare it as a `<servlet>` in your `web.xml` like so:

```
 <servlet>
  <description>An OAuth Servlet Controller</description>
  <display-name>OAuthServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>OAuthServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.neurologic.oauth.servlet.OAuthServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>config</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/oauth-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

And your servlet mapping:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>OAuthServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/oauth/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, that you have an OAuth servlet setup (bear in mind that `<load-on-startup>` isn't necessary but I like to have my servlets initialized before I use it), let's talk about configuring JOAuth.

The default JOAuth configuration file is `/WEB-INF/oauth-config.xml` (hence it doesn't have to be `<init-param>` in your servlet declaration).
The configuration file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oauth-config>
 <!-- Twitter OAuth Config -->
 <oauth name="twitter" version="1">
  <consumer key="TWITTER_KEY" secret="TWITTER_SECRET" />
  <provider requestTokenUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" authorizationUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" />
 </oauth>

 <!-- Facebook OAuth -->
 <oauth name="facebook" version="2">
  <consumer key="APP_ID" secret="APP_SECRET" />
  <provider authorizationUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" />
 </oauth>

 <service path="/request_token_ready" class="com.neurologic.music4point0.oauth.TwitterOAuthService" oauth="twitter">
  <success path="/start.htm" />
 </service>

 <service path="/oauth_redirect" class="com.neurologic.music4point0.oauth.FacebookOAuthService" oauth="facebook">
  <success path="/start.htm" />
 </service>
</oauth-config>
```

You'll notice that each `<oauth>` element has a `version` attribute (it's a compulsory attribute that's needed by the controller to know which oauth flow to use). These **only** have 2 possible values (`1` for OAuth1 and `2` for OAuth 2).
For OAuth 2, the `<consumer>` element doesn't have the `requestTokenUrl` attribute like its version 1 counterpart.

The OAuth Service is the one responsible for the OAuth handling. Each `OAuthService` is called by the controller through the `execute()` method.
There are 2 types of `OAuthService`:

- `com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth1Service`.
- `com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth2Service`.

**Note** For each service, if you're using OAuth 2, you **must** have a service that *extends* `OAuth2Service`. The same applies for OAuth 1. Failure to do that results in an exception being thrown.

Each `<service>` tag **must** have a `name` attribute that **matches** the `<oauth>` `name` attribute (Case sensitive).

Both `OAuth1Service` and `OAuth2Service` `execute(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` have been implemented to *best* handle the flow of the OAuth authorization protocol, but you can override it if you're not happy with it.

An example of the `com.neurologic.music4point0.oauth.FacebookOAuthService`:

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.oauth.enums.GrantType;
import net.oauth.exception.OAuthException;
import net.oauth.parameters.OAuth2Parameters;

import com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth2Service;
import com.neurologic.oauth.util.Globals;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 * @since 05 December 2010
 *
 */
public class FacebookOAuthService extends OAuth2Service {

 private static final String REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/Music4Point0/oauth/oauth_redirect";

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth2Service#processReceivedAuthorization(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)
  */
 @Override
 protected String processReceivedAuthorization(HttpServletRequest request, String code, Map<String, String> additionalParameters) throws OAuthException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
  parameters.setCode(code);
  parameters.setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);

  Map<String, String> responseMap = getConsumer().requestAcessToken(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, parameters, null, (String[])null);
  if (responseMap == null) {
   //This usually should never been thrown, but we just do anyway....
   throw new OAuthException("No OAuth response retrieved.");
  }

  if (responseMap.containsKey("error")) {
   throwOAuthErrorException(responseMap);
  }

  if (responseMap.containsKey(OAuth2Parameters.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
   String accessToken = responseMap.remove(OAuth2Parameters.ACCESS_TOKEN);
   request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.SESSION_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
   processAdditionalReceivedAccessTokenParameters(request, responseMap);
  }

  return null;
 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth2Service#processAdditionalReceivedAccessTokenParameters(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.util.Map)
  */
 @Override
 protected void processAdditionalReceivedAccessTokenParameters(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> additionalParameters) throws OAuthException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

Since Facebook still uses OAuth 2 draft 0 (zero), their access token doesn't do an HTTP 302 redirect, and that's why `processReceivedAuthorization()` is returns a null.
The `processReceivedAuthorization()` method allows the client to process received autorization `code` and **expects** an authorization URL (that's why it expects a return type of `String`).
If the method returns a `null` or an empty string, a url redirect never occurs.

Once the oauth flow has completed, the path in the `<success>` element is then called (through a `RequestDispatcher`), to show that OAuth is successfully completed.

To access the Access Token, (after successful logon via OAuth), do the following:

```
AccessToken accessToken = (AccessToken)request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.SESSION_OAUTH1_ACCESS_TOKEN); //For OAuth 1 access token
String accessToken = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.SESSION_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN); //For OAuth 2 access token.
```

I hope this little example helps those who are keen in making OAuth a worthwile experience for their development.

Sorry that I couldn't find the `community wiki` checkbox. Visit my blog (which has almost nothing on it) when you have time.

Adieu :-)

**PS** This is an implementation of the `TwitterOAuthService`:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.oauth.exception.OAuthException;
import net.oauth.signature.impl.OAuthHmacSha1Signature;
import net.oauth.token.AccessToken;
import net.oauth.token.AuthorizedToken;
import net.oauth.token.RequestToken;

import com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth1Service;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 * @since 05 December 2010
 *
 */
public class TwitterOAuthService extends OAuth1Service {

    public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_SESSION = "TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_SESSION";

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.neurologic.oauth.service.impl.OAuth1Service#processReceivedAuthorizedToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, net.oauth.token.AuthorizedToken)
     */
    @Override
    protected AccessToken processReceivedAuthorizedToken(HttpServletRequest request, AuthorizedToken authorizedToken) throws OAuthException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String requestTokenSecret = null;
        RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute(REQUEST_TOKEN_SESSION);

        if (requestToken != null) {
            requestTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
        }

        return getConsumer().requestAccessToken(null, authorizedToken, requestTokenSecret, new OAuthHmacSha1Signature());
    }
}
```

**Additional Resources**

- [OAuth 1 authorization with JOAuth, example needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355255/oauth-1-authorization-with-joauth-example-needed)