# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'oauth-config'. [2]

Tags: oauth-2.0, joauth

I have started implementing Joauth authentication. Ofcourse, right now i am doing copy paste to learn how it works.

currently i am facing issue
"cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'oauth-config'. [2]"

I have taken reference URL and that URL is beneath.

- [JOAuth, a java-based OAuth 1 (final) and OAuth 2 (draft 10) library. How do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376612/joauth-a-java-based-oauth-1-final-and-oauth-2-draft-10-library-how-do-i-us)

oauth-config.xml code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<oauth-config>
 <!-- Twitter OAuth Config -->
 <oauth name="twitter" version="1">
  <consumer key="TWITTER_KEY" secret="TWITTER_SECRET" />
  <provider requestTokenUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" authorizationUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" />
 </oauth>

 <!-- Facebook OAuth -->
 <oauth name="facebook" version="2">
  <consumer key="APP_ID" secret="APP_SECRET" />
  <provider authorizationUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" />
 </oauth>

 <service path="/request_token_ready" class="com.neurologic.music4point0.oauth.TwitterOAuthService" oauth="twitter">
  <success path="/start.htm" />
 </service>

 <service path="/oauth_redirect" class="com.neurologic.music4point0.oauth.FacebookOAuthService" oauth="facebook">
  <success path="/start.htm" />
 </service>
</oauth-config>
```

can u help what is the wrong here? i think we need to  add "dtd" file. can u please suggest me here. If you need any additional info, please suggest me.

Really appreciable,
Pradeep

Comment: Where are you running this poineer?

Comment: Elite... now it is working fine. there was jar problem in netbeans. i have updated the issue